# Attributive and predicative position of an adjective

Tags: nouns, adjectives, sentence, construction

I have some difficulty understanding the position of adjectives.
In English I have to put the adjective before the referred name (e.g., *I'm an Italian man*).

In some languages (as Italian or Ancient Greek), the adjective (or another grammatical element) can have two positions:

1. attributive: "gli uomini buoni" (the set of men who are good).
2. predicative: "i buoni uomini" (the men who are inherently good: all the men are good).

How do you translate?

1. the good men
2. ????

Comment: It is unclear what the nuances of the Italian phrases are. 'Predcative' makes it sound like 'The men are good' (that is you are dropping the copula 'are' in Italian). Can you elaborate?

Comment: The short answer is that in English we use vocal stress for what in Italian would be an out-of-normal-position word. See my longer answer below.

Comment: +1 Most questions of true merit come from the non-native speakers.

Comment: I believe both translate to 'the good men' in English, with the distinction being drawn from the semantics of the context: "those of the men who are good," and "the men, considering that all men are good."

Comment: @Mitch I think the OP has made his point sufficiently clear, if how I understand it is correct.

Comment: @mitch this is another example. "lo stesso scrittore" means "the same writer, not another"; "lo scrittore stesso" means "the writer bodily". I hope that the question is clearer.

Comment: @alepuzio: it's difficult to do translation without intimate knowledge of both languages. 'stesso' has a very particular meaning in Italian. And putting an adjective before and after a noun can have particular nuances (this change in meaning is common to Romance languages). But that doesn't guarantee a one-to-one translation to English. And you're using technical terms, 'attributive' and 'predicative' for a phenomenon in Italian. Are those the translations of the terms used to describe the situation in Italian?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The terms seem appropriate and may be traditional for Italian grammar, but they're not standard or useful for English. Forget the terms.

In Spanish, there's a similar phenomenon, with occasional modification of form, and usually some of meaning:

- *un hombre grande* 'a big man'
- *un gran hombre* 'a great man'

The Italian case seems to be a way of ensuring a [generic](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/generics.html) interpretation of the noun phrase; English normally uses articles for this, but English article use is very different from Italian.

If I've understood the distinction correctly, one might use a [generic NP](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html) in English to translate; i.e,

- *gli uomini buoni*  ~ *the good men* (referential NP)
- *i buoni uomini* ~ *good men* (generic NP)

Answer (score 5):

In English, adjectives  may have three different positions. But, using  any adjective at any   position is not  possible.

1) Attributive position - before noun. Most adjectives go before noun.

> Green tree
>   Happy girl

2) Predicative position - after verbs.

> The tree is green.
>   The girl is happy.

3.Postpositive - after nouns.

After certain nouns:

> Two meters tall
>   Two kilometers wide

Some fixed expressions:

> Court martial
>   Heir apparent

If there is an superlative adjective modifying noun,  adjectives ending in -able / -ible may come after that noun.

> worst choice imaginable
>   the best hotel available

Some adjectives can be used  both at "attributive" or "predicative" position. E.g;

> Happy girl
>   The girl is happy.

Some adjectives may have different meaning when used attributively and/or predicatively. E.g;

> My friend is poor.
>   My poor friend
>
> Robin Harris was late.
>   The late Robin Harris

Some adjectives, such as afraid, alive, alone can only be used at predicative position. E.g;

> John is alone.

Comment: For completeness, there is also the 'absolute adjective' (ambiguation problem' or 'adjective used in absolute construction'. Patterning on 'His energy almost spent, John flopped on the grass': 'Exhausted, John flopped on the grass'.  As explained elsewhere, short lone adjectives resist this usage: ??'Sad, John left the room to consider his future.'

Answer (score 3):

This is is the old problem of “May I introduce you to *mi bonita esposa* or to *mi esposa bonita*?”  Or if you prefer French, to *ma jolie femme* vs *ma femme jolie*.

Like Latin, Spanish (and to a lesser extent the other Romance tongues) use flexible word order where in English we use speech stress. You can only rarely use inversion in English for this, such as *to good men and true*. It doesn’t fit into normal speech as it does in Romance. Sometimes, though, the most important thing you can put at the front of the sentence, like that.

I think in English we would have to introduce someone to *your pretty wife or to your **pretty** wife*, setting the emphasized word in italic.  That’s a bit bludgeoning, though, so a careful writer will seek a way to do this without resorting to italic wherever possible.  It isn’t always possible though, so we go for the italic  in print, or to an underline in manuscript.

Comment: I have no idea what distinction of meaning is supposed to come from emphasising "pretty". If it were "**pretty** friend" I could suppose that meant *(as opposed to the other one - your ugly friend)*. But that's out, since you can only have one wife. I'm lost.

Comment: I'm still waiting for someone to fill me in on the [difference between *ma jolie femme* and *ma femme jolie*](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2134/ma-jolie-femme-vs-ma-femme-jolie#comment3687_2134). I speak a bit of French, but all I know is the first one sounds "non-standard".

Comment: @FumbleFingers As a native speaker, I think that *ma femme jolie* is wrong. The standard idiom is *ma jolie femme*.

Comment: @Evpok: I'm sure you're right. It's been a long time since I spoke any French, but I do know the adjective usually comes after the noun. I seem to recall being told there are some contexts where this is always or optionally reversed, but I don't remember any details, including whether any particular wordpair would be commonly understood to have two distinct meanings according to the order.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In Romance, if you put an adjective that normally goes in front in back, you are stressing it. *Mi viejo amigo* is “my old friend”, but *mi amigo viejo* is “my ***old*** friend”: by inverting the adjective, you emphasize it. In English we do with stress in our voice what in Romance they can sometimes do with word-order. The OP was trying to map his understanding  of this from Italian into English, but it just doesn’t work that way here. We can’t usually achieve emphasis by playing around with word-order, because our word-order is much more fixed than Italian’s. See now?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Adjectives that go in front are like our *descriptive* clauses, which can be omitted at will. Those that come afterwards are like the *restrictive* clauses that cannot be. The ones in front don’t distinguish which noun it is, they just add more description. This is the same in Italian and Spanish. e.g.: **The valiant soliders advanced** is “Los valientes soldados avanzaron”(=all advancing soldiers were valiant) *OR* “Los soldados valientes avanzaron”(=only the valiant ones did any advancing). “The soldiers, who were valiant, advanced” VS “The soldiers who were valiant advanced.”

Comment: @tchrist: Okay, I think I've finally got it, thanks. To summarise, putting the adjective in the "wrong" position emphasises it, and the context may allow this to be interpreted in some slightly "unusual" way. With your soldiers, the natural interpretation would be that all the soldiers were valiant, and they advanced. The "unexpected" word order encourages the somewhat "left-field" interpretation that some soldiers were not in fact valiant, and *only the valiant ones advanced.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, that’s it. The OP has some odd attributive/predicative terminology I’ve never seen before, but the issue maps exactly to descriptive/restrictive, which should be more clearly understood. He’s trying to find out how to do the same thing in English, and as I keep saying, English mostly doesn’t work that way by swapping word order. We use stress in our voice instead, or italic in print. BTW, you can take the normal SVO sentence ordering and screw it around to VOS or OVS or OSV to do the same emphasis trick in Spanish, Italian, and Portuguese, although not in French.

Comment: @tchrist: As a native and fluent speaker of French, if I introduced my wife to someone as *ma femme jolie*, I would not insist on the fact that she is pretty but that she is sweet/lovable to me. *Jolie* would not normally be used after the noun and doing so puts it in the category of adjectives that changes meaning depending on placement.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I really need an "authoritative source" on this one, so here's [Rob's English Blog](http://ictyenglish.blogspot.com/2006/01/grammar-tip-5-adjectives-after-noun.html):

Usually in English adjectives, or describing words, come before the noun:

- It was a large amount.
- He is a responsible citizen.
- She is an interested volunteer.

In order to put the adjective after the noun, you need to make a clause of some kind:

- It was an amount that was large.
- He is a citizen who is responsible.
- She is a volunteer who is interested.

However, look out for cases in English where the adjective comes after the noun. These are sometimes called participle adjectives. Look at these examples:

- I wrote to the person concerned.
- I got a rebate for tax paid.
- They worked through the night to repair the damage caused.

Notice that the adjective comes after the noun. It does not work before the noun. In these sentences, the relative clause is omitted and the participle becomes an adjective:

---

As Rob's blog goes on to say, some adjectives can go before *or* after the noun in certain constructions (note that this doesn't significantly affect the meaning):

- The stolen jewels were worth $2 million.
- The jewels stolen were worth $2 million.

...but this doesn't apply in OP's case, where *good* can only go before the noun. Any difference in meaning will have to be conveyed by using more words.

Comment: Right on. This is English Whiz-Deletion at work. However, I think it's different from what he's asking about, which is how to translate the construction from a language where it's used differently.

Comment: @John Lawler: Well you're the linguist, so perhaps you know Italian, and understand the distinction OP wishes to make. I don't, on both counts, so all I can do is tell him that even if he's used to being able to make some subtle distinction in Italian by this word-order switch, it probably doesn't work that way in English.

Comment: I think that's right. I don't know Italian, but when word order variation is available to make a distinction, the distinction can probably be made some way in any language. But probably not the same way.

Comment: @John Lawler: Even after seeing your answer and poring over OP's text, I still have no real clue as to the distinction he wants to make. But it does occur to me that in English, *"the errant knights"* means something completely different to *"the knights errant"* (though the latter is often, maybe usually, hyphenated).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: surely the position change makes a semantic difference in English. But we don't realy have an idea of what the meaning of the position change in Italian is, which may not correspond to a position change in English. I like translation questions, but the OP needs to provide  lot more for us to answer reasonably or it not to be 'off topic'.

Comment: @Mitch: I think in the case of *"knights errant"* it's not strictly true to say "the word order makes a difference in meaning". It just so happens that the (unusual) word order is a "set phrase". There may be other such word-pairs, but I don't think there's even a "partially-applicable" principle in English whereby *adjective+noun* conveys some generally-understood difference from *noun+adjective*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: agreed (that the change in syntax in Italian has a particular transformation meaning, but in English it is very idiomatic (and much rarer)).

Comment: @Mitch: I take it that means you *do* know Italian. But as we know, "translation" questions are very much off-topic, so you can't really expect much of that here. Incidentally, I did ask about [“ma jolie femme” vs “ma femme jolie”](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2134/) on french.se. I don't know if you know French, or if there's an italian.se, but such sites might interest you.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I don't know Italian. If I did, I'd more likely be able to answer the OP. I can almost remember the exact lesson in French which covered adjectives before and  after the noun (which is obviously shared by Italian). Your French.SE question is directly to that point, and the answers seem to correlate well with the OQ here (before the noun 'ma jolie femme' means my wife, who happens to be pretty, after the noun 'ma femme jolie' means of the wives that I have, the one who is pretty. But the OP hasn't gone so far as to clarify it this way for Italian.